# Print first 3 columns of CSV file in table format in PHP upon file upload

Tags: php, file-upload, html-table, import-from-csv

I am new to PHP and I am stuck with this problem.

```
$mimes = array('application/vnd.ms-excel','text/plain','text/csv','text/tsv');
if (((in_array($_FILES['uploadedfile']['type'],$mimes)))
    && ($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["size"] > 0))
{
    $filename = $_SESSION['username'].$_FILES["uploadedfile"]["name"];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["tmp_name"],"./uploads/".$filename);

    echo "Stored in: " . "./uploads/" .$filename;
    echo "<br />\n";
    echo 'Daylight hours will be calculated for this latitude : '.$_POST['latCSV'];
    echo "<br>";
    //print out uploaded file.csv
    echo "<table BORDER=1>\n\n";
    echo "  <tr><th>AvgCrown</th><th>MinCrown</th><th>MaxCrown</th><th>dateLogged</th><th>DaylightHours</th></tr>";
    echo "<tbody id='tblBdyLoggedData'>";
    $f = fopen("./uploads/" .$filename, "r");
    $i=0;   //just a counter
    while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach ($line as $cell) {
            // Save the value before you output
            $lastColValue = htmlspecialchars($cell);
            //unset($lastColValue[3]);
            echo "<td>" . $lastColValue . "</td>";

        }
        //checking if date is valid
        checkDateString($lastColValue);

        // If you want to store all log dates in an array:
        $logDates[] = $lastColValue;                            
        $firstlogDate = $logDates[$i];
        echo "<td>" . checkDateString($lastColValue) . "</td>";
        //call function using firstlogDate for every row
        echo "<td>" . calcDaylight($firstlogDate,$_POST["latCSV"]) . "            </td>";
        echo "</tr>\n";
        $i = $i+1;
    }
    fclose($f);
    echo "</tbody></table></body></html>";
}
```

**I would like to get print only the first 3 columns of the CSV file upon file upload** as the two other will be calculated using respective functions. Datelogged will be taken from the csv and reformated properly and daylight Hours is also calculated from datelogged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May this code will help you

```
?php
echo "<html><body><table>\n\n";
$f = fopen("so-csv.csv", "r");
while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {
        $count=0;
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach ($line as $cell ) 
        {
            if($count<3)
            {    
                echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</td>";
                $count++;
            }
        }
        echo "<tr>\n";
}
fclose($f);
echo "\n</table></body></html>";
```

Comment: @Hardik...well it does help but instead of giving me the first 3 columns, it just give me the first 3 rows. But thanks for the help!

Comment: I have updated my code that gives you first three line as three column of a table row

Comment: AvgCrown, MinCrown, MaxCrown, dateLogged
I want to pass all these values but I want to display only the first 3 columns in the table..

Comment: I have updated code. Please try this if any prob then tell me. I haven't tested this code so may be it has some error.

Comment: Did you change the code again..it seems to be broken now.. it worked when you had the if statement in it

Answer (score 2):

First, parse out the $file_contents using the PHP filesystem library:

$foo = split(',', $file_contents);

**Reference**: http://php.net/manual/en/book.filesystem.php

Now you can access the first three columns:

```
echo foo[0] . '/' . foo[1] . '/' . foo[2];
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace this:

```
                    foreach ($line as $cell) {
                        // Save the value before you output
                        $lastColValue = htmlspecialchars($cell);
                        //unset($lastColValue[3]);
                        echo "<td>" . $lastColValue . "</td>";

                    }
```

with this:

```
                    $lineValues = array_values($line);
                    if (count($line) < 3) {
                        echo "<td>This line is unusable</td><td></td><td></td>";
                    }
                    for ($colNum = 0; $colNum < 3; $colNum++) {
                        echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($lineValues[$colNum]) . "</td>";
                    }
```